# How to convert images selected to string for storing?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have images in Assets.xcassets named `city_00,city_01,...,city_10`

I stored them in an array

```
 let cityImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "city_00")!,UIImage(named: "city_01")!,.....UIImage(named: "city_10")!]
```

Then I call them using `collectionview` in my project and allow users to select any city they like

```
 var imageSelected = [UIImage]()
 var cityImage:UIImage?

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        cityImage = imageSelected[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
}
```

I like to save the selected image in database by converting them back into string. How do I do this?

Comment: Then just store the name string (`city_00 `,...), what's the real problem?

Comment: name strings takes more space than integers, that is why I was wondering

Comment: Take more space? its like few more bytes, it's not like you store the whole images...., if you don't want to waste some bytes then store Int is fine, store 00, 01,...

Comment: @Tj3n, my problem is now that I have no idea how to convert selected image into its string literals

Comment: Convert `cityImages` to array of strings, then use it on cellForRow to set it to image view

Comment: `let cityImagesNames: [String] = ["city_00", ""city_01",...]` `cityImage = [UIImage(named: cityImagesNames[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]]` or something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cityImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cityImage)
let imageString = cityImageData?.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: I have an attribute called storedImage of type string in model, I am getting this fatal error "reason=Source and destination attribute types are incompatible"

Comment: are you using core data? however, your question was about converting an image to string, if you alt + click imageString you'd find that it's of type string, I'm not sure about your model's attribute, maybe you can. send more code snippets so I can help

Comment: Appreciate it. Please see edited question. I am using core data.

Comment: I am sorry @leaner122 , I don't know much about core data, I don't use it for storing data, instead I use user defaults, maybe you can post another question that's related to core data so others can help with this issue